# GPU No Signal - 1070

Tags: gpu

I've been attempting to diagnose why my **NVidia 1070 Founder Edition** is not outputting to the screen. To diagnose I have:

- Tested HDMI, DVI-D and DP  (all worked elsewhere)
- Tested PCIe cables
- Reseated in PCIe16 and 8 slots

  I've confirmed with the PSU in the case/ on and using onboard it has worked.

What other diagnostics can we test?

Hardware:

1. Intel i7 4790k
2. NVidia 1070 Founders Edition
3. Intel 520 120GB SSD (x5)
4. Gigabyte Z97X Gaming-7 Mobo
5. 64GB Kingston HyperX DDR3 3300Ghz (OC)
6. Corsair 750W 80+ Gold Semi-Modular
7. Corsair 780T Black
8. Corsair 22′ Fan (x6)
9. Corsair H110i Water Cooler

In BIOS I've set it to PCI not IG.

Comment: Which motherboard are you using? It will make it easier to troubleshoot if you give us some more information about your current build.

Comment: Updated question